# Ctrl Button Sticks

Tags: keyboard, input

I am running windows XP, I have a MS Natural Erganomic Keyboard 4000 v1.0, now and again the Ctrl button will stick (not physically), usually in the process of changing to a different window. It happens around 6 or 7 times a day. Really annoying. I've changed Keyboards (same type). Anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: It isn't anything to do with accessability.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to a different (Brand/Model/Type) keyboard.

Comment: I don't want to (I'll vote for your answer though). Anyone know if this is the keyboard that is the problem?

Comment: the only way to know, is to plug in a different keyboard. Which I think is what matthew was referring to. If the control key sticks with a different keyboard then you know that yours is somehow the issue, probably because of a driver issue.

Comment: 5 years later, same problem, different keyboard (but same make/model), different computer, so I guess this must be some sort of driver issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the same problem, but I get this behaviour after using the mouse's wheel button to close Firefox tabs.

This is a configuration setting in the Microsoft's Intellipoint software, whereby the wheel button is configured to close the current window or tab.

Ctrl-W to close the tab or window does not have the same effect.

It is very annoying, but a single press on the Ctrl key does 'unstick' it.

As it happens, I also use a MS Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 v1.0, but I hadn't thought it was connected to this issue.